# Non-contiguous text Capture with Regular Expressions. How can I do it?

Tags: java, regex, formal-languages

I want to capture non-contiguous text from a string using a regular expression and I'm finding it extremely difficult. ( Couldn't make it work)

I have the following:

"John KC Mary V oranges."

KC and V are tags and they will always exist in my strings. I want to capture "John V oranges" in this case.

So what I want is to remove KC and everthing until V ( With the exception of V).

I can't figure out how to do that. I´m doing that on a Java code, so I think I have some syntax limitations for regular expressions.

And another limitation is that I need to do that only using regular expressions. I can't use java replace.

If you guys could give me some ideas I will really aprecciate.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK It is impossible to get non-continuous portions of the input in a single match.

You will have to use groups and/or replace to achieve what you want.

Comment: 1. Where is this in the overall text, start/middle/end, etc..? 2. Are you looking for word letters ("Jonh","oranges") or any characters, up/until/after/before anything else?

Comment: In most engines (not Dot-Net), there is a slight limitation in grouping. Geting array information per match is going to be limited to a single level of fixed, unquantified parenthesis. You can do `(John) KC Mary V (oranges)`, but if you do `(?:(John) KC Mary V (oranges) .+?)+` capture groups 1 and 2 will be overwritten each quantified pass of the expression. Effectively containing the last values found of John,oranges.

Comment: The text is a single sentence. I'm analysing sentence by sentence. I think Nyx is right. It is impossible to get it in a single match.I wanted it in a single match if possible.

Comment: @Row - It's actually possible to get every single portion/sub-string/character or anything else contained in any text of any type in a _single match_.

Comment: Can you explain me how sln? A teacher from my university told me that in theory it is possible to subtract two groups, which would be exaclty what I wanted to do. ( Match "KC Mary"  than remove it from the whole)  But he doesnt know if Java have the sintax to do that. Sorry if you told me how on your first comment I couldn't fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following regex

```
([a-zA-Z ]+)KC [a-zA-Z]+ (V [a-zA-Z]+)
```

Which will return an array like

```
Array
(
   [0] => John KC Mary V oranges.
   [1] => John
   [2] =>  V oranges.
)
```

and you can pick the last 2 indexes.. Simple ..

Comment: So it is impossible to get it in a single match right?

Comment: Roiw.. Yes ..Your requirement is to actully capture 2 portions of a string. now to get a them you can use above Regular expression..

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex for the search replace:

```
KC.*?\s(?=V)
```

It means anything after KC followed by V. And considering there is a space before the V.

Above regex is when you want to do search replace. But if you want to do it using regex match then the regex will be:

```
(.*?)\sKC.+(\sV.*)
```

After performing the regex match, just concat the group-1 and group-2 of the returned match.

Comment: This will return me "KC Mary ". Which is perfect if I could use a String.replace.  But I cant use a String.Replace.

I need a regexp that would return me exactly "John V oranges".

Comment: Post your code at where you use regexp. The regexp is correct. I suspect you are using it wrongfully.

Comment: got it. you don't want to use regex-replace instead you want to have it as regex-match.

Comment: Yep you got it! Thats my problem. I'm starting to think that there isnt a solution for that.

Comment: So it is impossible to get it in a single match right?

Comment: To me its impossible. But to other regex experts it may be not! You should wait for their response :-)