# REGEX_EXTRACT in Google SQL

Tags: sql, extract

I have a string that looks like this:

```
DadC - Review Vid - Vid - Eng - Owner: TC
```

How can I regex extract using SQL the first word and the last word after Owner in one capture group?

Currently in google SQL I have a query that looks like this to extract the last word:
`SELECT *, REGEX_EXTRACT(column_name, r'(\bOwner.*\b)')` but how do I add the first word in one capture group?

I want an output that looks like this:
'DadC - TC'

Comment: How about a concatenation of two separate `REGEX_EXTRACT` results?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: What is the 1st word, what is the 2nd word in this example? I think I'd go with regex replace instead and capture these word and put them in the replacement depending on what your desired results should look like.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include the desired result for your example.

Comment: You can not get 2 separated matches in 1 capture group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's impossible to capture non-contiguous parts of a string into a single capturing group, I suggest capturing your two desired parts separately and then concatenating resulting strings.

```
SELECT *, 
       REGEX_EXTRACT(column_name, r'^(\w+)\b') || ' - ' ||
       REGEX_EXTRACT(column_name, r'\bOwner:\s*(\w+)\b')
```

The above is untested but should give you good idea about the suggested approach.

Here's a good general read on your case of capturing: [Non-contiguous text Capture with Regular Expressions. How can I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916834/non-contiguous-text-capture-with-regular-expressions-how-can-i-do-it)